# How can i use orderby only for every 10 rows in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by, row

I need order every 10 row of a single column table and fetch the rows of n interval. Iam using where mod(rownum,10) for doing the second part. But i cant find a way to orderby every nth row before fetching the first and last row of n rows.Please help
The table is like =>

```
Column
15
18
13
14
11
16
17
12
19
20
9
2
3
5
4
6
7
8
1
10
```

This is the query iam currently using==>

```
Select column
from (select column,row_number() over (order by column) as rn
      from table
     ) t
where mod(rn,10)=0 or mod(rn,10)=1;
```

This will fetch

```
Column
1
10
11
20
```

But what i want is

```
Column
11
20
1
10
```

Ps: i cant orderby whole column then fetch every 1st and 10th row,i want to orderby first 10 column fetch 1st and 10th row then orderby next 10 colum fetch 11th to 20th etc..

And i can only fire the query one time only

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: I don't understand how you expect to sort the results.  There's no guaranteed order to the data in the column and you say the table only has a single column, so there's nothing else we can use to sort the data.  If we can't sort by the data in that column, there's no way to get a deterministic order.

Comment: `.. order by rn` ?

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no such thing as the nth row unless a column specifies the ordering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
SELECT col, rn, (rn - 1) / 10 AS trunc
  FROM (SELECT col, row_number() over (order by col) as rn
          FROM data
     ) t
 WHERE mod(rn,10)=0 or mod(rn,10)=1
 ORDER BY (rn - 1) / 10 DESC
;
```

Result:

```
+------+----+-------+
| col  | rn | trunc |
+------+----+-------+
|   11 | 11 |     1 |
|   20 | 20 |     1 |
|    1 |  1 |     0 |
|   10 | 10 |     0 |
+------+----+-------+
```

[Working Example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=aac5c2beb9d64b8ef5e58540321485be)